# Как изучить ООП?

Tags: ооп, любой-язык

Я уже год изучаю программирование, пишу в основном на Pure C и Perl. Очень нравятся мне эти языки, но при написании кода всегда придерживаюсь процедурного и императивного стиля программирования. Хочется попробовать другую парадигму, вот подумал изучать ООП. Нашел учебники, а в них все примеры на Java или C#. Есть ли учебники по ООП без привязки к конкретному языку программирования?

Comment: Вроде есть, но как вы собираетесь учить ООП, не изучая язык, поддерживающий эту парадигму? Определитесь с языком (я бы порекомендовал C# (на мой взгляд самый перспективный на данный момент), но можете Java или С++) и ищите любую книгу по этому языку для начинающих.

Comment: Спасибо, уже нашел! Гради Буч "Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование" вроде без особой привязки к конкретному языку. Кстати perl поддерживает ООП. Правда, оно у него весьма странное, судя по отзыву коллег.

Comment: @vaster1, будьте готовы к тому, что все (или почти все) книги такого плана на 90% состоят из банальностей ("лучше быть здоровым и богатым, чем бедным и больным"), часто облеченных в наукообразную форму.

--

Реальная проблема в изучении ООП это выбор подходящей задачи. 

Для тривиальных задач из большинства учебников ООП не нужно, там оно просто "притянуто за уши" и вызываает только раздражение.

Обучение же на задачах, где ООП нужно, обычно невозможно из-за их большой трудоемкости (для них оно и придумано).

Вполне вероятно, что все это для Вас очевидно, поэтому и задаете такой вопрос.

Comment: @avp Это Вы о чём? О том, что 

     Object-oriented programming generates a lot of what looks like work. (П. Грэм)

Об этом?

Comment: @alexlz, это тоже правильное замечание.

Но я имел в виду именно содержание (content) большинства книг об ООП.

Comment: @vaster1 Вы будете большим молодцом, если сможете с нуля изучить ООП по книге Буча. Это я к тому что его нужно читать уже имея представление об ООП. Я бы посоветовал следующий рецепт: читать статьи/книги полегче, плюс устроиться на работу. Через год в голове значительно прояснится.

Comment: @avp а какая задача для ООП будет подходящей? (Раньше я думал, что это -- симуляционное моделирование. Но в статьях последних лет утверждается, что и там есть более приемлемые подходы, напр. AFRP. Увы -- не специалист, так что аргументировать не смогу)

Comment: @alexlz, про новшества в моделировании тоже  не знаю. 

Оно безусловно подходит, вспомним, что С++ (точнее его предшественник -- Си с классами) появился именно из этих задач.

Оконные системы подходят. Вывод на печать (но это тоже похоже на окошки). 

Наверное многие прикладные задачи управления ресурсами, ну они по сути являются моделированием.

Но, думаю, что в любом случае важен масштаб проекта, *количество* программистов.

Comment: @avp Лёгкий аромат холивара. Кроме Си с классами что-то мне вспоминается название simula-67. А, кстати у Дала в "Структурно программировании" (Дейкста, Хоор, Дал) -- не оно?

А насчёт количества программистов... У Грэма фраза про "похоже на работу" идёт третьим пунктом. А второй:

Object-oriented programming is popular in big companies, because it suits the way they write software. At big companies, software tends to be written by large (and frequently changing) teams of mediocre programmers. (Ну и далее по тексту http://www.paulgraham.com/noop.html , пункт в комментарий не лезет)

Comment: @alexlz, холиварить (а точнее флудить) что-то неохота. А за наборчик эссе спасибо! 

Похоже, там есть что почитать на досуге.

Answer (score 19):

> Хочется попробовать другую парадигму, вот подумал изучать ООП. Нашел учебники, а в них все примеры на Java или C#. Есть ли учебники по ООП без привязки к конкретному языку программирования?

Очень сложно найти учебник по ООП, в котором вообще не будет примеров кода. Да и вообще, язык примеров не должен быть ключевым при выборе хорошего учебника.

Любая концепция проектирования находит свое отражение в синтаксисе языка программирования, поэтому полностью "абстрагироваться" от языка не получится. С другой стороны, хорошая книга раскрывает суть концепций, что позволяет читателю применять их в любом языке программирования.

Существует несколько очень хороших книг по проектированию, ООП и паттернам.

Если опыта не очень много, то я бы рекомендовал начать ["Head-First Design Patterns"](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/blog-post.html) (есть на русском). Несмотря на желтоватое название и наличие фразы "паттерны проектирования" в названии - это один из лучших учебников по ООП и принципам проектирования.

После этого, я бы рекомендовал бы взяться за один из более фундаментальных учебников, типа Гради Буча ["Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование с примерами приложений"](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2009/09/blog-post_15.html), Бертрана Мейера ["Объектно-ориентированное конструирование программных систем"](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2012/03/blog-post_19.html) или Крэга Лармана ["Применение UML и паттернов проектирования"](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2015/03/applying-uml-and-patterns.html). Но тут уже нужно понимать, что это не диванное чтиво и на любую из этих книг уйдет добрые полгода достаточно плотной работы (но эти усилия окупятся).

Я какое-то время назад сделал подборку книг по дизайну и ООП, к ней всегда можно возвращаться, когда появится желание пополнить свои знания по этой теме: ["Книги по дизайну и ООП"](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/07/books-on-design-and-ood.html).

P.S. Изучение разных подходов к проектированию - это именно то, что отличает хороших разработчиков! Борьба со сложностью - это наше все, а без должного понимания, как правильно анализировать и разбивать задачу на более мелкие куски, решения будут не самыми удачными с точки зрения долгосрочной перспективы.

Answer (score 5):

Интересно, а зачем изучать парадигму, если использовать её Вы не собираетесь (судя по "без привязки к языку")? Чтобы иметь представление, я думаю, и статьи на Википедии хватит. Для более глубокого ознакомления необходимо изучать конкретный язык, так как в каждом языке подход к этой парадигме свой. Реализация ООП в SmallTalk совсем не похожа на реализацию ООП в C++, например. Попробуйте Java, C# или Ruby. Ну можно и C++, Вам так проще будет, но я считаю, это не тот язык, с которого стоит начинать учить ООП...

Answer (score 5):

"Есть ли учебники по ООП без привязки к конкретному языку программирования?" и "Как изучить ООП?" - концептуально разные вопросы. Ждать универсального ответ на оба вопроса сразу бессмысленно. Я попробую ответить на второй вопрос.

ООП - парадигма, и изучать ее нужно практически. Парадигму не изучить "теоретически" ровно так же как не изучить "теоретически" английский или другой разговорный язык.

Совет 1: языки программирования создаются сразу с заточкой на какую-то парадигму. Это не значит, что они ограниченны этой парадигмой, это говорит лишь о том, что нет универсального языка для все парадигм сразу. И по этому ты не сможешь глубоко понять и изучить ООП без использования языка, который заточен именно на работу с ООП.

Совет 2: я сомневаюсь, что ты поймешь ООП из книги. Я изучал ООП в институте и самостоятельно из ряда книг, но до сих пор от проекта к проекту открываю для себя ООП заново, каждый раз понимая все больше и лучше суть объектов, их роли, качества, значимости, ответственности и взаимодействия. Будь готов к тому, что прочитанной ты поймешь гораздо-гораздо позже, после 100500-кратного практического применения.

Answer (score 4):

предположим вы нашли книжку по ООП в чистом виде, с большой вероятностью вам будут обьяснять основы на каком-то алгоритмическом языке что добавит определенную сложность и усложнит понимание, с другой стороны у вас не будет возможности запустить програмку и попробовать самому что-то там поменять.

нет ничего плохого в том что вы потратите несколько дней на изучение синтаксиса другого языка ведь принципы написания кода те же, единственное что меняется это синтаксис (более того изучение синтаксиса нового языка позволяет взглянуть на код который вы писали раньше под другим углом)

из личного опыта: до того как начать изучать ООП в институте я уже был знаком с несколькими языками. понимание пришло только когда начал изучать java, ведь там ООП начинается уже с `hello world`

Answer (score 4):

Лучшая рекоммендация, которую можно дать при таких ограничениях, - это книга Бертрана Мейера "Почувствуй класс". И хотя в ней есть привязка к конкретному языку, очень легко притвориться, что её нет, поскольку этот язык Eiffel. Крайне маловероятно, что вам когда-нибудь придётся программировать на этом языке в реальной жизни. Так что во время чтения книги можно смело считать этот язык вымышленным и несуществующим. Как будто бы он был придуман специально для данной книги.

Answer (score 3):

В книге **Дейтел Х.М., Дейтел П.Дж. Как программировать на C++** - сразу начинают объяснения с классов, без долгого и унылого разжевывания про переменные, массивы и прочее, и изложено хорошо и понятно.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к ответу Сергея Теплякова, где он перечисляет рекомендуемые книги, могу порекомендовать еще одну из серии "Head First" - "Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование". Она не может претендовать на всеобъемлющее введение в предмет, но круг рассматриваемых полезных вещей обширен - анализ предметной области,проектирование, адаптация к требованиям, которые постоянно изменяются. Рассматриваются некоторые общеизвестные принципы ООП (принцип открытости/закрытости, единственной обязанности и т.д.). Подача материала, как всегда в книгах серии "Head First", в развлекательном стиле.

Примеры даны на Java, это один из самых простых языков программирования, понимание примеров труда не составит.

Как введение в предмет, книга заслуживает внимания.

Answer (score -2):

попробуйте с UML начать. там рассматриваются взаимосвязи обьектов. к тому же в UML редакторах есть генераторы кода из UML в другие языки.

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю его тоже.

Comment: по UML много книг

Comment: Ни разу еще не видел, чтобы UML реально использовался в реальной жизни (ну кроме понтов манагеров). Полностью согласен с известной критикой UML:

>Obviously the UML will not be useful to any software developer. 
>Could it perhaps be useful to someone else? Project managers, 
>perhaps? Company executives? The companies themselves? Of course 
>not. Indeed the documents make no pretense of such usefulness, and 
>for good reason. It is hard to imagine what benefit a business 
>could get from pages of cryptic diagrams about hazy properties of a 
>poorly understood system.

Comment: я и не говорю что это лучше чем разрабатывать иерархию классов в голове. просто я думаю парню надо разобраться что такое моделирование классов. просто надо из умл ухватить вводную часть и все

Comment: @perfect: для того, чтобы изучать ООП, надо писать с ним реальные программы. Понимание основных принципов при чтении литературы приходит быстро, проблемы начинаются с тем, чтобы «уложить» эти принципы в рамки конкретной задачи и конкретного кода.

Я, например, видел много людей, которые боятся объявить «лишний» тривиальный класс из ложно понятых соображений эффективности.

Comment: может я не прав но прежде чем написать класс надо понять что это. обратного вроде метода нет. просто я знаю людей которые пробовали программировать и им показывали код класса а они не могли отличить класс от его экземпляра и чем дальше в лес тем больше дров. мне повезло я по хорошей книге учился. но там перед вводом в классы кусок UML был разжован.

в UML хорошо расписаны такие понятия как инкапсуляция, наследование, полифоризм, делегация и тп. Мне кажется сначала надо понять что это, а потом уже брать конкретный язык разработки и уже в нем реализовывать все это.

Comment: @perfect ООП -- это не моделирование классов.

Answer (score -3):

Важно понять, что ООП почти никогда не нужно. Есть такие узкие темы, где оно может пригодиться, как GUI и крайне особые случаи моделирования, где есть объекты с индивидуальными таймингами и сложным поведением. Первое к задачам, решаемым на языках C и Perl, очевидно, отношения не имеет. Можно программировать десять лет или всю жизнь, но так и не столкнуться с задачей, где бы введение ООП однозначно дало бы какую-то пользу. Чаще всего его внедряют просто "потому что могут", соответственно, используя неправильно, зря и только усложняя работу.

Comment: Категорически с вами не согласен. Если его используют, значит это кому-то нужно. Любой подход (функциональный, процедурный, объектно-ориентированный) имеет свои недостатки и преимущества. 
И ООП используется не только в GUI, но и в серверной части. 
Точно так же можно сказать: "можно программировать веб-сайты 10 лет, но так и не столкнуться с задачей, где введение AJAX дало какую-то пользу, значит AJAX почти никогда не нужен". Или "я пишу на ассемблере, значит мне C и Perl не нужен, а значит и никому не нужен"

Comment: Если вы хотите донести до автора, что Х не нужен и вреден, то стоит подкрепить это какими-нибудь доказательствами.

Comment: Вы только что нарушили несколько законов логики. Например, предлагая ненужную вещь, вместо доказательства необходимости, кто-то по-вашему должен доказать обратное. Тогда я настаиваю, чтобы бы попрыгали на левой ноге и купили зеленую мазду. Но даже ваши прыжки и мазда не помешают вашим соседям и коллегах, чего нельзя сказать о внесении лишней парадигмы в код.

Comment: Nakilon, давайте вы не будете подкапываться - ничего я не предлагал, кроме подкрепления доказательствами.

Comment: @Etki, предлагаю предъявить доказательства необходимости предъявлять доказательства ненужности вещи, доказательства нужности которой вами не предъявлены.

Comment: Nakilon, вы не заработаете себе уважения такой коммуникацией.

Comment: @Etki, вы считаете этот сайт филиалом конкурса Мисс Мира, где нужно придумывать такие ответы, чтобы в ответ шли аплодисменты? Жаль, но я думал, что здесь главной целью является учиться писать хороший код.

Comment: Nakilon, я сейчас не про количество плюсов под комментариями и в профиле.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22835/discussion-between-nakilon-and-etki).